# How do I construct string from byte array in D

Tags: string, size, d, zero-copy

I have array of bytes which is defined as pointer + size:

```
  size_t size;   // size in bytes
  void   *data;  // NOT zero-terminated string
```

How do I construct, preferably zero-copy, 'string' from it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This assumes that `data` points to immutable memory:

```
string s = (cast(immutable(char)*)data)[0..size];
```

If it doesn't, a `char[]` would be more appropriate instead of a string, or you can make an immutable copy with `.idup`.

Comment: The opposite would be: size=s.length; data=cast(void*)s.ptr; ?

Comment: Yep! If `data` is actually `const(void)*` (as it should be, since string contents are immutable), then the cast will be unnecessary.